# Is it possible to prove not equals is irrelevant without funext?

Tags: agda, dependent-type

I can trivially prove that not equals is irrelevant with function extensionality:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≢_)
open import Relation.Binary using (Irrelevant)
open import Relation.Nullary.Negation using (contradiction)
open import Axiom.Extensionality.Propositional using (Extensionality)

postulate
  fun-ext : ∀ {ℓ₁ ℓ₂} → Extensionality ℓ₁ ℓ₂

≢-irrelevant : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → Irrelevant {A = A} _≢_
≢-irrelevant {x} {y} [x≉y]₁ [x≉y]₂ = fun-ext (λ x≈y → contradiction x≈y [x≉y]₁)
```

This seems impossible to prove without funext when A is polymorphic but is it possible when `A = ℕ` or `A = Bool`?

Comment: What is the definition of `Irrelevant` that you are using?

Comment: Edited in imports to make things clear. I am using the standard library definition of irrelevance: https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Binary.Definitions.html#4926

Comment: I don't think you can prove this even for the unit type. Proving equality of functions is just not a thing, outside of really trivial cases, without funext.

Answer (score 0):

This is not provable without funext. We did [consider changing the definition of the empty type](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/issues/645) to make these provable however it was deemed too invasive a change.